# How to clear data from Streams of blocpattern?

Tags: flutter, dart

**My this function isn't clearing the cart.**

```
clearCart(){
    _listController.close();
  }
```

Am I supposed to call some other property or implement some other approach in clear cart function?
Here is my CartListBloc code:

```
class CartListBloc extends BlocBase {
  CartListBloc();

  var _listController = BehaviorSubject<List<FoodItem>>.seeded([]);

//provider class
  CartProvider provider = CartProvider();

//output
  Stream<List<FoodItem>> get listStream => _listController.stream;

//input
  Sink<List<FoodItem>> get listSink => _listController.sink;

  addToList(FoodItem foodItem) {
    listSink.add(provider.addToList(foodItem));
  }

  removeFromList(FoodItem foodItem) {
    listSink.add(provider.removeFromList(foodItem));
    
  }
  clearCart(){
    // What should I put here to clear the bloc of Streams from cart
  }

//dispose will be called automatically by closing its streams
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _listController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Stream` class has a `drain` method, which removes all data from a `Stream`. However, you seem to be trying to clear a `BehaviorSubject` so you can't use `drain` ([It doesn't actually clear the subject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/issues/233)). Instead, you should probably simply add an empty `List` or `null` (in which case you need to deal with this `null` in your UI) to `_listController`, which will give you a new event with no items.
Edit:
Example:

```
_listController.add([]); //Now your listeners will receive
                         //new event with empty list of items
```

Comment: Creating empty list for _listController llike ```_listController=BehaviorSubject<List<FoodItem>>.seeded([]);``` doesn't remove items from the stream so they remains in the cart. How do I remove the items from cart when navigating back after placing order in my App?

Comment: No, I said you should `add` the empty list. I'll update my answer with more details